# Laravel Telescope : error message in production logs

Tags: laravel, telescope

I use Laravel Telescope locally. It works very well.
In production, I disabled it but I noticed an error in the daily log file.

> [2022-12-29 00:00:03] production.ERROR: There are no commands defined in the "telescope" namespace. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\NamespaceNotFoundException(code: 0): There are no commands defined in the "telescope" namespace.

In the local log file, I don't have this message.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Delete

```
"laravel/telescope"
```

in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a command set to run at midnight that does something on Telescope.

Have a look at at `App\Console\Kernel.php` and see which commands are running at midnight.

If you need the command locally, but don't want it on production, wrap it in something like this:

```php
if (config('app.env') === 'local') {

}
```